# Using SQL Replace to emulate group-concat, but getting the wrong results

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-concat

I have this table with 2 columns, ParameterID and HDFID.

```
ParameterID HDFID
7   1
7   2
7   3
32  1
32  3
42  1
42  2
42  3
44  1
44  2
44  3
48  1
48  2
48  3
51  1
51  2
51  3
52  1
52  2
52  3
```

i want to turn this into

```
ParameterID HDFID
7           1/2/3/
32          1/3/
42          1/2/3/
44          1/2/3/
48          1/2/3/
51          1/2/3/
52          1/2/3/
```

But this is what I'm getting.

```
ParameterID HDFID
7           1/2/3/1/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1
32          1/2/3/1/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1
42          1/2/3/1/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1
44          1/2/3/1/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1
48          1/2/3/1/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1
51          1/2/3/1/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1
52          1/2/3/1/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1/1/2/3/3/2/1
```

This is my code,

```
SELECT     ParameterID, HDFID = REPLACE
                          ((SELECT HDFID AS [data()]
                              FROM HDfParameters b
                              WHERE  b.ParameterID = ParameterID
                              ORDER BY b.ParameterID FOR xml path('')), ' ', '/')
FROM         HDfParameters
WHERE     ParameterID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ParameterID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing the correlation between inner and outer queries. Because your `WHERE b.ParameterID = **ParameterID**` had no prefix, it was actually `b.ParameterID` since "b" is in the inner query.

```
SELECT     ParameterID, HDFID = REPLACE
                          ((SELECT HDFID AS [data()]
                              FROM HDfParameters b
                              WHERE  b.ParameterID = HDfParameters.ParameterID
                              ORDER BY ParameterID FOR xml path('')), ' ', '/')
FROM         HDfParameters
WHERE     ParameterID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ParameterID
```